# Programmatically generating a drop-down menu

Tags: php, html

I have a drop down menu below:

```
  $form = "
<form action='" . htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "' method='post'>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td><select name='year' id='yearDrop'>
<option value=''></option>
<option value='$getyear[1]'>1</option>
<option value='$getyear[2]'>2</option>
<option value='$getyear[3]'>3</option>
<option value='$getyear[4]'>4</option>
<option value='$getyear[5]'>5</option>
<option value='$getyear[6]'>6</option>
<option value='$getyear[7]'>7</option>
<option value='$getyear[8]'>8</option>
<option value='$getyear[9]'>9</option>
<option value='$getyear[10]'>10</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
";
```

Notice the drop down menus are in a php varaible in a form. My question is: "is there a much better and shorter method of displaying the drop down menu above?". Maybe by using some sort of loop to loop through each value and give each option the same `value` attribute?

I want to use `getyear` in order to fit in a simple if statement:

```
    if ($getyear){
    echo "year is chosen";
    }else{
    $errormsg = "You must enter in Student's current Academic Year to Register";
              }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<?php  

  $getyear = (isset($_POST['year'])) ? $_POST['year'] : '';
  $errormsg = (isset($errormsg)) ? $errormsg : '';

$min_year = 1;
$max_year = 10;
$years = range($min_year, $max_year); // returns array with numeric values of 1900 - 2012
$yearHTML = '';
$yearHTML .= '<select name="year" id="yearDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
$yearHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
foreach ($years as $year) {
    $yearHTML .= "<option>$year</option>".PHP_EOL;  // if no value attribute, value will be whatever is inside option tag, in this case, $year
}
$yearHTML .= '</select>'; 

  if( (isset($_POST['registerbtn']))){
      $getyear = $_POST['year'];

      if (!in_array($getyear , $years)){
      echo "year is chosen";
                    }else{
              $errormsg = "You must enter in Student's current Academic Year to Register";
          }

            }

  $form = "
<form action='" . htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "' method='post'>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td id='errormsg'>$errormsg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Year:</td>
  <td>{$yearHTML}</td>
  <td><input type='text' name='year' value='$getyear' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><input type='submit' value='Register' name='registerbtn' /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>";

  echo $form;

?>
```

Comment: All your option values ... are the same? Or am I missing something fundamental here...

Comment: I think you are looking for a checkbox.

Comment: @RussellDias I was not sure if I was allowed to use same value for each option. Is there a way that each option contains its own value by using dimensional array e.g. `$getyear[1]`, `$getyear[2]` `$getyear[1]` etc. If so then what do I write in the if statement to see if a value from the drop dowm menu is selected?

Comment: Giving each option the same value attribute is equivalent to giving the user only one option.  What does $getYear represent?

Comment: @moonDogDog I will edit the code to give each drop down a different value, can I ask what the if statement should be then with the updated values?

Comment: Why don't you just get rid of the value attribute and check for `> 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foreach` loop is extremely beneficial when looping over arrays and performing operations on their values.

[foreach control structure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
<?php
// reference values for output and for validation later
$min_year = 1900;  // using as an example
$max_year = 2012;
$years = range($min_year, $max_year); // returns array with numeric values of 1900 - 2012

// for HTML output
if (empty($_POST)) {  // display form
    $html = '';
    foreach ($years as $year) {
        $html .= "<option>$year</option>";  // if no value attribute, value will be whatever is inside option tag, in this case, $year
    }
    // output HTML
    echo $html;
} else {  // process form
    $chosen_year = isset($_POST['year']) ? $_POST['year'] : "";
    if (!in_array($chosen_year , $years) {  // year is invalid
        $errormsg = "You must enter in Student's current Academic Year to Register";
    } else {  // year is chosen
        echo 'year is chosen';
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one quick question, at top of the page I need to include an isset, so could the isset look exactly like this: `  $getyear = (isset($_POST['year'])) ? $_POST['year'] : '';` this is so I don't get undefined index

Comment: If there is a select option with "year" as the name attribute in your form, it will not matter if the user entered anything or not.  From what it looks like in your question above, the default option will be an empty string, as it is the first option in the list.  In other words, if $_POST is not empty and your form has been submitted, your year index will be there.  That being said, it certainly doesn't hurt in case JavaScript or something else removed it, so I have amended the answer to reflect this precaution.

Comment: I have included an update in my question on my code, I havn't quite seem to get it working, can you have a look and see where I am going wrong because I don't know where I am going wrong

Comment: If you want to use $getyear as a test for a conditional statement, then you can use $getyear = in_array($_POST['year'], $years), which returns boolean true or false.  Then you can simply use if ($getyear) echo 'year is chosen';.  What exactly is happening with your script?

Comment: Its ok you fixed the problem. It was returning the boolean which was the problem, I have marked your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This file will generate the `select` options automatically, and give you an easy place to do further processing.

```
function process_form(){
    if(!isset($_POST['year']) || !is_numeric($_POST['year'])){
        // Form invalid
        return false;
    }

    $year   = $_POST['year'];

    // Perform actions - save to database, etc..?

    // Form valid
    return true;
}

$error  = false;
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    // Form submitted
    $result = process_form();
    if($result){
        ?>
        <p>Valid year selected</p>
        <?php
        exit;
    }

    $error  = true;
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<?php if($error){ ?>
    <p class="error">You must select the student's current academic year to register</p>
<?php } ?>
<label for="select_year">Academic Year:</label>
<select name="year" id="select_year">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php for($year = $start_year; $year <= $end_year; $year++){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $year;?>"><?php echo $year;?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

<button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```